# ROW_NUMBER() over (Partition by....) to return specific row

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions, row-number, partition-by

My query looks like this:

```
with T1 as (
Select
Dept_No,
Product_No,
Order_No,
Order_Type
Row_number() over (partition by Product_ID order by Order_No desc) as "COUNT"

From Orders_Table)

Select * from T1
where ("COUNT"  = '1' and "Order_Type" <> 'Cancel')
or ("COUNT" = '2' AND "Order_Type" <> 'Cancel'
```

So I'm trying to pull the most recent order that was not canceled.
Essentially my ROW_number() over (partition by...) function labels the orders in sequential order with 1 being the most recent order and 2 being the second most recent order.
The issue is that with this query it pulls both the most recent, and 2nd most recent order.
I am trying to write this to where if it only gives one or the other.
So if COUNT = 1 and the order_type is not cancel, only show me that record.
If not then show me the 2nd.

This is being done in Toad for Oracle 9.5 using SQL tab.

Comment: Input/Output, please.

Comment: Add the "Order_Type" <> 'Cancel' to the cte, and then only look for "Count" = '1' in the second query.  Try that.

Comment: Websch01ar.  I just was thinking that right before I read your comment. Great  idea! Let me check and then mark as answer

Answer (score 3):

But you have an or.
If both or are satisfied you will get two rows.

```
with T1 as (
Select
Dept_No,
Product_No,
Order_No,
Order_Type
Row_number() over (partition by Product_ID order by Order_No desc) as "COUNT"
From Orders_Table
where "Order_Type" <> 'Cancel')

Select * from T1
where "COUNT"  = '1'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a case expression to control which rows get a result from row_number(), here we avoid numbering any rows that have been cancelled:

```
WITH t1 AS (
      SELECT
            Dept_No
          , Product_No
          , Order_No
          , Order_Type
            /*  the most recent order that was not canceled */
          , case when order_type <> 'Cancel' 
                 then ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Product_ID 
                                          ORDER BY Order_No DESC)
                 end AS is_recent
       FROM Orders_Table
      )
SELECT
      *
FROM t1
WHERE is_recent = 1
```

Or, perhaps the easiest way is to simply exclude cancelled orders e.g.

```
WITH t1 AS (
      SELECT
            Dept_No
          , Product_No
          , Order_No
          , Order_Type
          , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Product_ID 
                                          ORDER BY Order_No DESC)
                 AS is_recent
       FROM Orders_Table
       WHERE order_type <> 'Cancel' 
      )
SELECT
      *
FROM t1
WHERE is_recent = 1
```

nb: row_number() returns an integer, so don't compare that column to a string